# Exchange web services Error - The Autodiscover service couldn't be located

Tags: sharepoint, exchangewebservices, web-parts

I am using Exchange Web Services(EWS) to create outlook meeting invite in SharePoint Visual Web Part. Following is the code snippet to get the instance of EWS.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
service.AutodiscoverUrl("firstName.Lastname@xxxxxxxx.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
```

When I use it in test console application, it is working properly. But if I use it in Visual Web Part on same server with same user account, then it gives following error.

> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.AutodiscoverLocalException: The Autodiscover service couldn't be located.
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.InternalGetLegacyUserSettings[TSettings](String emailAddress, List`1 redirectionEmailAddresses, Int32& currentHop)
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetLegacyUserSettings[TSettings](String emailAddress)
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.InternalGetLegacyUserSettings(String emailAddress, List`1 requestedSettings)
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Autodiscover.AutodiscoverService.GetUserSettings(String userSmtpAddress, UserSettingName[] userSettingNames)
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.GetAutodiscoverUrl(String emailAddress, ExchangeVersion requestedServerVersion, AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback validateRedirectionUrlCallback)
>      at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.AutodiscoverUrl(String emailAddress, AutodiscoverRedirectionUrlValidationCallback validateRedirectionUrlCallback)

Answer (score 0):

Not that familiar with Visual Web Part, so I'm not sure exactly what the user context is that you are running under there.  As an experiment, can you specify actual credentials in the program above (rather than `UseDefaultCredentials`) and see if it successfully runs?  If so, then you either need to specify the creds in your code or find a way to change the user context of Visual Web Part.

If that *doesn't* work, then you might have to enable tracing on the ExchangeService object and see what's happening under the covers.  My experience has been that AD error reporting is very limited until you see what's coming back on the HTTP layer.